# Android application text Alignment mismatched on various devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am new to android development, I have developed simple android application in which text aligned properly on some mobile devices and messed up on some mobile devices.  Can any one help me to identify exact cause of issue and provide solution to solve it.

Below configuration in build.gradle file :

- minSdkVersion 18
- targetSdkVersion 29

Layout used in activity is:

- androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Please let me know if any other information would be needed.

Comment: Attach your XML

Comment: Problem is in your paddings. It's better to define textview and edittext in horizontal linearlayout and give weight to them and set their gravity to center.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin, Then should I remove the padding and follow the way you suggested?

Comment: Yes, try that to be sure

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin, Can you help me what weight and where to apply please?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin, Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/emailtext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left" />
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/passwordtext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left" />
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```